# Is React suitable for multi page applications?

Tags: javascript, client, reactjs

I'm currently developing a Single Page Application (in this case AngularJS), but as it grows I find it more and more tempting to refactor it into a multi page app.

However, I still need the ability to have sophisticated, dynamic UIs on the client (which requires more than just DOM manipulation but *awareness* of my information model).

I know most people use jQuery for this; I'm afraid it won't get me as far as I want, and I'm wondering if ReactJS is suitable for that job (well, when you're running a small company, not Facebook).

Comment: You might want to look into the relatively *new* idea of "isomorphic javascript".  Which React is good at. This looks like it covers most of it: http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-javascript-future-web-apps/

Answer (score 7):

To be quite honest I've tried the single page app route with Angular, Backbone and even Knockout to an extent.

In my efforts I've found the most maintainable solution, especially for large teams is to use a multi-page app and rely on React to create a dynamic single page type experience where it's necessary.

Due to the buzz term SPA I've found a lot of teams think they need to be cutting edge by adding unnecessary complications like an SPA where a standard multi-page MVC app is a much better solution.

To me, React is the perfect solution for the problem of building a large scale website which may act as a multi-page app in some areas where necessary, but use standard sane MVC elsewhere.

React just works very easily with Django, ASP.NET, Ruby etc...

Comment: Thanks! Could you detail what the limiting factors were with SPAs?